# iterating bash script for cycle in a file

Tags: command-line, bash, java, sed

I try to make this very simple bash program that must make the following operations:

1. modify a file java n times: every time I must change a single word in a single line of the file (the line is 11) I know there is the following command that replace a single word in a particular line of a program wih another one:

   ```
   sed -i "11s/1/$n/" IC_masslessPlanetesimal.java
   ```

   if I do the above command I can modify only one time the file.java because in the second iteration of the for cycle I have not the same word as in the first iteration: I start with 1 in line 11, than in the fist iteration I change with `$n` (that is equal to 2), but now **HOW** I can modify the `sed` command to change again the word (that is now equal to 2) to have, for example, 3 in the 11th line?
2. compile the file java: it's ok;
3. modify a file.txt: again the same problem as in 1) I want to change a word in a line iteratively with a for cycle or something like that;
4. pass it to an executable file: this is the second problem. I have modifIed the param.txt file and now I want to read it into an executable file called **exec**. If I do this from the terminal I must launch the exec. program with the command `./exec` and after that I must write from screen the file.txt name. Now is it possible to launch a program from bash and read with it the file.txt? I try with:

   ```
   sed -i "13s/Zero/$n/" param.txt
   ./exec < param.txt
   ```

that script must change the line 13 from Zero to $n in param.txt **how** I can launch the exec program with the command `./exec` with the specific param.txt file.

```
#!/bin/bash

n=0
for n in "2" "3" 
do
  sed -i "11s/1/$n/" IC_masslessPlanetesimal.java
  javac IC_masslessPlanetesimal.java  
  java IC_masslessPlanetesimal
 sed -i "13s/Zero/$n/" param.txt
 ./exec < param.txt   
done
```

thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Why not start with template files instead of banging up the existing ones?

Comment: why don't you just change your java program to accept ARGUMENTS instead!  Then you don't have to do this hack!  In your script, just write out `n` to a file and the next time you run, you `cat` the file into a variable, add 1 to the value and write it back to the file. Then run the java program passing in an argument.

Comment: What you're doing (though needlessly complicated) should work fine. What is the actual problem you have?

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of editing the file in place:

   ```
   sed -i "11s/1/$n/" IC_masslessPlanetesimal.java
   ```

   copy it into a template file, say IC_masslessPlanetesimal.java.template, then create a new version of it for each n:

   ```
   sed "11s/1/$n/" < IC_masslessPlanetesimal.java.template > IC_masslessPlanetesimal.java
   ```
2. 
3. Same as 1
4. Yes, `./exec < param.txt` is correct.  Doesn't that work?